# Field Values to Column Names in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

How do I convert this:

```
Name    Attributes
----    ----------
John    Height
John    Weight
John    Age
Mary    Shoe Size
Mary    Hair Color
Mary    Eye Color

to this:    

Height  Weight  Age
```

Name and Attributes are two fields in an Access table.  I want to convert the Attribute values into fields names based on the value in the Name field.  I am using MS Access 2010.

I presume I do something to the effect of **select ??? from table where name="John"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 'Value' field to your table so it will read like this:

> ```
> Name  Attributes  Value
> ----  ----------  -----
> John  Height      172
> John  Weight      87
> John  Age         25
> Mary  Shoe Size   9.5
> Mary  Hair Color  Brown
> Mary  Eye Color   Blue
> ```

You can use 'TRANSFORM' and 'PIVOT' in Access

```
TRANSFORM FIRST(Value)
SELECT Name FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name
PIVOT Attributes
```